# Progress Bar for Copying Files using an Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, progress-bar

I have an if statement that checks if a directory exists and if it does it copies that folder to the specified location.

The entire copy process is on an array of pre-determined folder locations, for loop goes through the array and copies the folder and its data at each location.

At the moment there are 200 different locations to copy with more still to be added.

I am trying to implement a progress bar around the copying of these 200+ folders but keep running in to errors, I think the issue I am having is mainly due to the array, the tutorials I've seen (which differed greatly from one another) covered just basic file copying.

Any help or tips on how to get a progress bar working would be much appreciated :)

```
for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.Length; i++)
{

   string sourcePath = pathArray[i];

   //MISSING CODE

   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
   {                   

      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPathProper);

      foreach (string dirPath in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath,"*",
          (System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)))
      {
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, 
                targetPathProper));
      }

      foreach (string newPath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*", 
          (System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)))
      {
         System.IO.File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcePath, 
             targetPathProper), true);
      }

   } //end if
} // end for
```

Comment: What kind of errors? Please be more specific. Is your question relating to the errors, or how it implement a progress bar?

Comment: Download the source of vXCopy (C# 2.0) and learn from the implementation. Better yet, just use it as is. http://vxcopy.codeplex.com/

Comment: My question is how to implement it sorry :P At the moment I am just reading up on the backgroundWorker :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you get an error, what error are you getting?

As for your progress bar, you can simply increment at each base directory in the array.  No real need to increment for every file.  Or if there is a need to indicate progress on every file you can have two progress bars.

```
progressBar1.Maximum = pathArray.Length;
progressBar1.Value = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < pathArray.Length; i++)
{

   string sourcePath = pathArray[i];

   progressBar1.Value++;

   if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
   {                   

      System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPathProper);
      string[] subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath,"*",(System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
      progressBar2.Maximum = subDirs.Length;
      progressBar2.Value = 0;
      foreach (string dirPath in subDirs)
      {
         progressBar2.Value++;
         System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, 
            targetPathProper));
         Application.DoEvents();
      }

      progressBar2.Value = 0;
      foreach (string newPath in subDirs)
      {
         progressBar2.Value++;
         System.IO.File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcePath, 
             targetPathProper), true);
         Application.DoEvents();
      }

   } //end if
} // end for
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was that simple :P 

I now just need to read up on getting it to work on a background worker so the UI doesn't look like it's frozen :P

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] subDirs = 
            System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*",
            (System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                int subFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
         SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
 progressBar1.Maximum = subFiles+(subDirs.Length);
 progressBar1.Value = 0;
 foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*",
       SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 {
       progressBar1.Value++;
       progressBar1.PerformStep();
       Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
       Application.DoEvents();   

 }

 foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 {
       progressBar1.Value++;
       File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
       Application.DoEvents();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Backgroundworker but if you want to use an additional method 
here is a link with downloadable source code that will also help to get you started since I am assuming this is a winforms application

[How to copy files in C# with a customizable progress indicator and or progress bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36647/How-to-copy-files-in-C-with-a-customizable-progres)

Answer (score 0):

try
            {
                string[] subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", (System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories));
                int subFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
                progressBar1.Maximum = subFiles+(subDirs.Length);
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*",
                       SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    progressBar1.Value++;
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }

```
            foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
                 SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
                File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath), true);
                Application.DoEvents();

            }

        }
```